# Cascaded PID loop and parallel PID loop

Tags: electrical-engineering, control-engineering, control-theory, robotics, pid-control

What are cascaded and parallel PID loop and what are the differences between them. I searched on google and came across few websites but still i don't understand the the two types of control loops ?

Answer (score 1):

In cascade, the output of one controller will be the input to the other.

In parallel the controllers are stacked and the outputs from these controllers will combine to give 1 output.